# Why does $\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ look different to what I expect it should look like on WolframAlpha as x approaches 0?

Tags: real-analysis, graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%281%2Fx%29%2C+-0.01+%3C+x+%3C+0.01

[image]

$$$$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%281%2Fx%29%2C+-0.001+%3C+x+%3C+0.001

[image]

$$$$

For  larger intervals of x, such as $ -0.1< x< 0.1,\ $ the graph looks how I would expect it to look.

My suspicion is that the graphs that WolframAlpha is plotting are wrong/misleading as $ x $ gets close to 0.

Unless I'm wrong and the graph on WolframAlpha is correct, which would be totally fascinating.

What I think the function *should* look like is basically cot(x) but getting more and more squished in the x-direction as $ x {\to} 0$.

To be more precise, the qualitative properties I expect tan(1/x) to have for each interval $ \frac{1}{(k + \frac{1}{2})\pi} < x < \frac{1}{(k - \frac{1}{2})\pi}, k \in \mathbb{Z} $ are:

1. $\tan(1/x)$ is coming from $+ \infty$ when x is just greater than $\frac{1}{(k + \frac{1}{2})\pi}$
2. $\tan(1/x)$ is approaching $0$ from above for x just less than $\frac{1}{k\pi}$
3. $\tan(1/x)$ is approaching $0$ from below for x just greater than $\frac{1}{k\pi}$
4. $\tan(1/x)$ goes down to $- \infty$ when x is just less than $\frac{1}{(k - \frac{1}{2})\pi}$

Comment: Although you say that the result does not match what you expected it to look like, you haven't actually said what you expect it to look like.

Comment: I would expect the neighborhood around 0 to be pretty much a solid vertical blue band. What are you expecting, since you don't say? I would not expect WolframAlpha to show you anything meaningful. The function is highly singular there.

Comment: @ Lee Mosher - Yes that's a good point. Let me think about it and then edit my question

Comment: If by a "vertical blue band", you mean kind of like how "sin(1/x) is a rectangular blue band" near x = 0 then I can see what you mean, although I actually think my description of it being like cot(x) but squished more and more together as $ x {\to} 0 $ is more "accurate" of a qualitative description of the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica (11.3) replicates your plot.  I've also instrumented it to see how many times it evaluates the function to make the plot.

```
counts = 0;
Plot[Tan[1/x], {x, -1/100, 1/100}, EvaluationMonitor :> counts++]
counts
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
4288
```

So the function was (only) evaluated 4288 times to get the plot you see.  In the part near $x = 0$, picking a random $x$ and evaluating it essentially gives a random height, so we should expect to see something unstructured there.  What if we force more points to be more evenly sampled?

```
counts = 0
Plot[Tan[1/x], {x, -1/100, 1/100}, PlotPoints -> 100000, EvaluationMonitor -> counts++]
counts
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
1946107
```

and perhaps what you see is closer to what you expected, although the plot code evaluated the function nearly 2 million times to do so.

Do we have to be so aggressive with sampling?  Apparently not, if we let the plotting functions sample more finely where the function seems more wildly behaved.

```
counts = 0;
Plot[Tan[1/x], {x, -1/100, 1/100}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 15, EvaluationMonitor :> counts++]
counts
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(I cheated.  There's no visible difference between the two plots, so I reused the same uploaded image.)

```
507263
```

So it can be done with about one quarter as many samples.

---

Where are these sample points?

```
samples = Reap[
    Plot[Tan[1/x], {x, -1/100, 1/100}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x,Tan[1/x]}]]
];
Length[samples[[2, 1]] ]
Show[samples[[1]] , ListPlot[samples[[2, 1]], PlotStyle -> Red ]]


4288
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where the features are wide, the sampling seems to do fine.  There's a little bit of [wagon wheel effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect) near $x =  \pm 0.005$, where the samples are nearly horizontal nearly linear bands.  The samples corresponding to the tops and bottoms of the filled in parts around those same $x$s are easily visible.  At a guess, they seem to correspond to incorrectly classified turning points of the function.  Not sure why the algorithm "ignores" the outliers farther away from the $x$-axis than these samples.  Closer to zero, around $[-0.002, 0.002]$ the points seem to be vaguely randomly distributed with a distribution that is peaked near the $x$-axis (as we would expect from the function we are plotting).

If we increase the number of starting samples,

```
samples = Reap[
    Plot[Tan[1/x], {x, -1/100, 1/100}, PlotPoints -> 500, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, Tan[1/x]}]]
];
Length[samples[[2, 1]] ]
Show[samples[[1]] , ListPlot[samples[[2, 1]], PlotStyle -> Red ]]

27360
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We see broadly similar behaviour.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought it should look like.

Comment: Rather curious what could explain the parabola-like arc artifacts in the initial image.    Using regularly spaced x-values doesn't give this effect.  Is there some special algorithm Mathematica uses to choose points that causes it?

Comment: @JairTaylor : Plotted up the sample points.  The parabolic features seem to be misclassified as turning points of the function.

Comment: Huh, neat. Thanks!